# Populate does not seem to populate for all the array elements

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

Consider the code below:

```
const aux = await Fasta.find({}, "healthyTissue")
    .limit(1)
    .populate({
      //---------------------first level (healthy or tumor fasta file) ----------------
      path: "healthyTissue",
      model: "Hidden",

      options: {
        limit: 2
      },

      //---------------------    second level (hidden documents)       ----------------
      populate: {
        path: "children",
        options: {
          limit: 2
        },
        model: "FastaElement"
      }
    });
```

This is the output:

[image]

The problem: **just the first children is populated**. I have double-checked the database, and *it is not empty*.

I feel that I have seen this problem, but I cannot remember where. *Could anyone refresh my memory?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `perDocumentLimit` to your populate options:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.populate

> For legacy reasons, limit with populate() may give incorrect results because it only executes a single query for every document being populated. If you set perDocumentLimit, Mongoose will ensure correct limit per document by executing a separate query for each document to populate().

Comment: thanks, I was programing something from zero. I remember I saw this problem somehow, however, I cannot remember where. Thanks!