# Is it possible to read from mongoDB in batches?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a huge dataset in MongoDB, I had to save it by parts using `create`, in batches of say 1%. 
Now I want to read it back. I know that nodeJS can take the heat because I read it into a local variable before saving to mongo and send it to Angular. I get the error below, but I do believe that this erros is coming from MongoDB/Mongoose.

It would be nice if I could read data from Mongo by parts.

```
(node:1096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_BUFFER_OUT_OF_BOUNDS]: Attempt to write outside buffer bounds
```

**Background**: I am using mongoose and populate, see here: [Populate does not seem to populate for all the array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997183/populate-does-not-seem-to-populate-for-all-the-array-elements/60999564#60999564)

It works if I limit the populate number of documents.

here goes the schema I am trying to recover:

```
const FastaSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  header: headerSchema,
  healthyTissue: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Hidden" }],

});

const hiddenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  children: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "FastaElement" }]
});

const fastaElement = new mongoose.Schema({
  description: String,
  sequence: String,
  comments: String
});
```

Here goes the code that I am using to populate:

```
app.use("/", async (req, res) => {
  const aux = await Fasta.find({}, "healthyTissue").populate({
    //---------------------first level (healthy or tumor fasta file) ----------------
    path: "healthyTissue",
    perDocumentLimit: 1,
    //---------------------    second level (hidden documents)       ----------------
    populate: {
      path: "children",
      perDocumentLimit: 1,
    },
  });

  const aux2 = [];

  aux.forEach((element) =>
    element.healthyTissue.forEach((hidden) =>
      hidden.children.forEach((leaf) => aux2.push(leaf))
    )
  );

  res.json(aux2);

});
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048384/easiest-way-to-load-documents-from-mongodb-collection-in-chunks-of-10) helps

Comment: thanks I will take a look!

Comment: If it helps, you can upvote that answer.

Comment: it seems that I need to organize the dataset?! I have no order! Are you sure your solution will give all the elements in the dataset. I have never used aggregate, but heard a lot. It seems that it like popule.

Comment: It may work even without and order, but to be safe it is good to order by a field.

Comment: I need to populate, does it still work? I am taking a look at your solution!

Comment: In aggregation framework, we have [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup) instead of populate.

Comment: Can you add your schema codes and sample documents?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210891/discussion-between-jorge-pires-and-suleymansah).